# find $f_{Y}(y)$ of $y=2x+4$

Tags: probability, random-variables

The random variable $X$ is $N(5,2)$ and $y=2X+4$.
Find:

a) $\eta_y$

b) $\sigma_y$

c) $f_Y(y)$

My attempt:

I have solved a and b as follow:

a) $\eta_y = 2\eta_X+4 = 14$

b) $\sigma_y^2 = 4\sigma_{x}^2 = 16,  \sigma_y = 4$

c) how can I solve $f_Y(y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to guarantee that

$$
f_X(x)dx = f_Y(y)dy ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ f_Y(y) = f_X(x)\left| \frac{dx}{dy} \right|
$$

where the absolute value is used here to ensure that $f_Y(y) \ge 0$. In this case $dx/dy = 1/2$ therefore

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_x^2}} e^{-\left(\frac{y-4}{2} - \eta_x\right)^2/2\sigma_x^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(4\sigma_x^2)}}e^{(y - (2\eta_x + 4))/2(2\sigma_x)^2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_y^2}}e^{(y-\eta_y)^2/2\sigma_y^2} \tag{1}
$$

This last step just shows that $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(\eta_y = 14, \sigma_y = 4)$. Below there's a small simulation, the blue histogram is built by generating $10^5$ points $ X ~\mathcal{N}(5,2)$ and then transforming them according to $Y = 2 X + 4$. The red line is Eq. (1)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By definition:
$$\begin{align*}f_Y(y) &= P'(Y \le y) \\ &= P'(2X + 4 \le y) \\ &= P'\left( X \le \frac{y - 4}{2}\right) \\ &= \frac{1}{2}f_X\left(\frac{y - 4}{2}\right)\end{align*}$$

And $f_X$ you should know…